# Python: Conditionals With Comparisons

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started learning Python. So I'm still pretty confused with the conditionals if and else. Especially, now the assignment ask for boolean string. I have tried multiple ways but I can only get one code to work. In addition, if there are multiple conditions, with many (more than two) possibilities. Do we still use string such as outcome = ['a', 'b', 'c' ] to define the variables first?

```
subject_age = ['old','young']

change_analysis = True 

if subj_age == 'old':

   print_analysis = True

else: 

   print_analysis = False
```

When the subject is 'old', the code works perfect fine. But, when I test with the subject is 'young', the code still does not work.

​

```
# Change subj_age
subj_age = 'young'
​
# Re-run code and make sure the conditional still works
%run -i ./A1Code/q7_code.py
assert not change_analysis
assert isinstance(change_analysis, bool)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Downloads/A1Code/q7_code.py in <module>()
      6 # Re-run code and make sure the conditional still works
      7 get_ipython().run_line_magic('run', '-i ./A1Code/q7_code.py')
----> 8 assert not change_analysis
      9 assert isinstance(change_analysis, bool)

AssertionError:
```

I keep getting Assertion Error

Comment: I also do not quite get hat you are asking. A list can not be equal to a string. You can check if your string is part of your list using `in`: `print("Egg" in ["Young","Old"])` -> `False` or `print("Old" in ["Young","Old"])` -> `True`. Your task needs no `if` - simply do `change_analysis = subj_age == "old"`

Comment: Because the assignment ask to include Conditionals with Comparisons. Such as, Write a conditional with an if and an else:
The if should check if the variable subj_age has the value 'old' (a string).
If so, it should set the variable change_analysis to the value True (a boolean)
Else, the variable change_analysis should be set to False (a boolean) 

I got the first part, but the second part I'm still confused

Comment: Is there any reason why you have `subject_age = ['old','young']`? It doesn't seem like your assignment mentioned it should be a list instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your if-statment currently checks if the value `'old'` is equal to your array `['old', 'young']` (obviously it's not the same)

To check if a subject is contained within your array you use `in`

```
if 'old' in subj_age:
    #stuff
```

Inverse operator:

```
if 'old' not in subj_age:
    #stuff
```